# Fitnesse: Is it possible to RUN Fitnesse pages on wiki server?

Tags: fitnesse

Fitnesse: Is it possible to RUN Fitnesse pages on wiki server?

Answer (score 0):

Fitnesse includes its own Wiki server.
Does that have a limitation you are trying to overcome?
Do you have a particular alternate Wiki server product in mind?

Comment: yes, currently I am running it from Fitnesse wiki server, however I am trying to combine the existing test pages with the enterprise wiki and want to make it shared

Comment: Can you clarify? What are the existing test pages? Do you mean existing FitNesse pages or pages from some other system?  What is the enterprise wiki? Is this a FitNesse wiki or some other system?  I think what you want can probably be done but I need more details to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed it:

```
<iframe height="90%" width="90%" frameBorder="1" src="http://your.fitnesse.server/">this browser does not support IFRAMEs</iframe>
```

Then change your .../FitNesseRoot/files/templates/sidebar.vm to:

```
  #if( $actions.suitePage )
  <a href="http://your.fitnesse.server/$localPath?suite" accesskey="u" target="_blank">Suite</a>
  <a href="http://your.fitnesse.server/$localPath?suite&amp;remote_debug" accesskey="d" target="_blank">Debug</a>
  #end
  #if( $actions.testPage )
  <a href="http://your.fitnesse.server/$localPath?test" accesskey="t" target="_blank">Test</a>
  <a href="http://your.fitnesse.server/$localPath?test&amp;remote_debug" accesskey="d" target="_blank">Debug</a>
  #end
```

Adding:

- http://your.fitnesse.server/ to each href attribute
- target="_blank" to each  element

You will then be able to see the test pages on your wiki, being able to run the tests in a new browser window.

If you omit the second part (target attribute), your tests will appear as being run on your wiki server.